# POST requests redirects, but AllowAutoRedirects = false gives 302 exception, how to avoid it?

Tags: c#, redirect, request, header, httpwebrequest

I'm making a tool to check a login on a website, AllowAutoRedirect = false crashes the program with a 302,
Sending all the headers and cookies and payload goes fine on AllowAutoRedirect = true goes fine but I need to gather the cookies from the domain before the redirect.

How to? Thanks.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

payload
requestheaders

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
      stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
      stream.Close();
}

request.AllowAutoRedirect = false; <-- crashes here (302 Found Exception)


var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: "AllowAutoRedirect=false" means "I'm going to handle all 302 myself correctly". So far I don't see any indication that code in the post is doing so - please make sure to actually provide [MCVE] that includes how you handle 302.

Comment: In order to handle the 302 means I would need to do a try catch, but inside the try I would need to have the var response, meaning I can use it outside of it, what I should do? @AlexeiLevenkov , Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a try catch block solves this issue, inside the catch you can get the response from the server and be able to handle the response there.

```
try
{
     //All your request code here...
     var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
     var response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;   
     //handle the request here
}
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation about what's your code do.